# Recyclerview muestra datos repetidos

Tags: java, android, cursor, arrayadapter

Tengo 2 registros insertados en una tabla SQLite y los cargo a una array para mostrarlos en un recyclerview con un Adapter, pero en el recyclerview me muestra el segundo registro dos veces, aquí dejo el código:

```
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  listCreditos=new ArrayList<>();
  arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
  _inicio= new Inicio();
  idU=getArguments().getString("idU");

  if(GetListCreditos())//llenar array desde sqlite

  arrayList=GetArrayListInicioItem();
  adapter = new InicioRecyclerAdapter(context, (ArrayList) arrayList, idU);
  recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter); 
  layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
  recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
  return rootView;
  }

public boolean GetListCreditos() {
  con=new conexion(context);
  con.open();
  bd=con.getReadableDatabase();
  inicio=null;
  String query="Select * from " + Inicio.TInicio +" where   IdU= '"+idU+"'";

  Cursor cursor=bd.rawQuery(query, null);
  if(cursor !=null && cursor.moveToFirst())
  {
  do {
  id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(_inicio.id));
  estatus=cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(_inicio.Estatus));
  Nombre=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(_inicio.Nombre));
  inicio = new Inicio(id,estatus,Nombre);
  listCreditos.add(inicio);//aqui se cargan los dos registros que hay
  } while (cursor.moveToNext());
  }
  else{
  Toast.makeText(context, "No se encontraron datos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
  cursor.close();
  return true;
  }
```

Hice este metodo para pasar el array de la consulta a otro array para que mapee los datos en otra clase y poder mostrarlos:
El problema es aquí, porque es donde me duplica el dato, nose, pero creo yo que es cuando envio las variables estatus y Nombre, al parecer "toman" el ultimo valor agregado es por eso que se duplica siempre el ultimo dato.
Espero haberme dado a entender.

```html
 public ArrayList<InicioItem> GetArrayListInicioItem(){
      if(listCreditos != null) {
      for (int i = 0; i < listCreditos.size(); i++) {
      inicio = listCreditos.get(i);
      arrayList.add(new InicioItem(_inicio, context, estatus,Nombre));
      }
      }
      return arrayList;
      }
```

Adapter

```html
 Adapter


      public class InicioRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<InicioRecyclerAdapter.InicioRecycler iewHolder> implements Filterable {
      private ArrayList<InicioItem> arrayList = new ArrayList<InicioItem>();
      private Context context;
      String idU;

     public InicioRecyclerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<InicioItem> arrayList,  String idU) 
       {
             this.context = context;
             inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
             this.arrayList = arrayList;
             this.idU=idU;
       }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(InicioRecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
        InicioItem inicioItem = arrayList.get(position);
    holder.imgvInicioImgBackground.setImageResource(inicioItem.imgBackground());      
    holder.imgvInicioImg.setImageResource(inicioItem.img()); 
    holder.txtvInicioNombre.setText(inicioItem.nombre());
    }
    }
```

Clase para mapear los datos del query 
InicioItem

```html
public class InicioItem {
      int  img, imgbackground, estatus;
      String Nombre;

       private Inicio _inicio;

      public InicioItem(Inicio inicio, Context context, String Nombre, int estatus) {
            this.estatus=estatus;
            this.Nombre=rNombre;
            this.context=context;

            this._inicio=inicio;
            _inicio=new Inicio();

        }

        public Inicio inicio(){
                return _inicio;
        }

        public int imgBackground(){
        imgbackground = R.drawable.background_item_red;
        if(_inicio != null){
        switch (estatus){
        case 0: 
       imgbackground =  R.drawable.background_item_red; break;
        case 1: 
        imgbackground =  R.drawable.background_item_teal; break;
        case 2: 
        imgbackground =  R.drawable.background_item_blue; break;
        }
        }
        return imgbackground;
        }

        public int img(){
        img = R.drawable.ic_item_no_asignado;
        if(_inicio != null){
        switch (estatus){
        case 0: 
        img =  R.drawable.ic_item_no_asignado;
        break;
        case 1: 
        img =  R.drawable.ic_item_activo;
        break;
        case 2: 
        img =  R.drawable.ic_item_convenio_promesa_pago;
        break;
        }
        }
        return img;
        }

        public String nombre(){
        String nombre = "Nombre: ";
        if(_inicio != null){
        if(Nombre != "")
        return nombre +Nombre;
        }
        return "";
        }
        }
```

Comment: hola, podrias hacer debug y revisar el tamano de tu arrayList en tu Adapter para verificar que solo hay 2 items :D?

Comment: hola @Carlosgub en array del adapter solo tiene los dos items

Comment: @A.Cedano en la consulta si me trae los datos correctamente pero al momento de pasarlos al arraylist y mostrarlos parece que me repite el segundo

Comment: Realmente tu código está escrito de una forma algo difícil de entender. ¿Cuál es el array que debería presentar los datos en el recycler?  ¿Qué significa esta llamada: `arrayList=GetArrayListInicioItem();`?  ¿Por qué este if: `if(GetListCreditos())`? ¿Si dentro del `do...while` donde aparentemente llenas el array imprimes cada dato también se imprime la segunda fila dos veces? ¿Cómo es posible que se imprima dos veces si dices que la consulta trae los datos bien? La única explicación es que se añada desde otra parte. Traté de analizar la lógica de tu código y me resultó imposible...

Comment: Si dices que los datos estan bien el problema deberia estar en el InicioRecyclerAdapter() pero no podria darte una respuesta sin ver el codigo de esa clase.

Comment: @ErickSilva ya he agregado el codigo, gracias

Comment: Yo primero comprobaría que al hacer la consulta, el resultado no esté duplicado. Si el resultado no está duplicado, debuggea el método que va añadiendo elementos al ArrayList, a ver si ahí están los datos duplicados y comprobar en qué momento ocurre, ya que es ese array de items el que se le pasa al adapter. Nota: Es importante crear POJOS (Java) o data class(Kotlin) en el repositorio que mapeen el resultado de la capa de datasource para pasarlos al model, de esta manera cuando pedimos datos, si el resultado no es el esperado y la lectura es correcta, sabremos que el error puede estar en el ma

Comment: Hola al hacer la consulta el dato no esta duplicado, el método que va añadiendo elementos al ArrayList es donde se duplica, y lo hace desde el principio ya pero no tengo idea de como solucionarlo ya que ese método si se debe hacer. Espero usted me entienda. Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deberías de limpiar tu lista antes de cualquier nueva adición, con el método `clear()` para la `arrayList`.

```
public ArrayList<InicioItem> GetArrayListInicioItem() {

  arrayList.clear()

  if(listCreditos != null) {
    for (int i = 0; i < listCreditos.size(); i++) {
      inicio = listCreditos.get(i);
      arrayList.add(new InicioItem(_inicio, context, estatus,Nombre));
    }
  }
  return arrayList;
}
```

Es posible que el query se este llamando más de una vez por lo tanto se adicionan duplicados.